# NULL значение в Relationship MySql

Tags: mysql, база-данных

Имеется таблица:

```
CREATE TABLE `chat` (
  `id` BIGINT(6) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `siteId` BIGINT(6) NOT NULL,
  `clientId` BIGINT(6) NOT NULL,
  `operatorId` BIGINT(6) NOT NULL,
  `guest` TINYINT(1) NULL DEFAULT 1,
  `theme` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
  `name` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
  `complete` TINYINT(1) NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `created` TIMESTAMP(6) NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`, `siteId`, `clientId`, `operatorId`),
  INDEX `fk_chat_site_idx` (`siteId` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_chat_client1_idx` (`clientId` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_chat_user1_idx` (`operatorId` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_chat_site`
    FOREIGN KEY (`siteId`)
    REFERENCES `site` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_chat_client1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`clientId`)
    REFERENCES `client` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_chat_user1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`operatorId`)
    REFERENCES `user` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Штука в том что привязка по полю operaotrId при создании записи в таблице будет NULL, то бишь чат изначально создается без оператора ну и как следствие запись не вставится. Убрать у поля `NOT NULL` мне кажется не совсем правильным. или это не так?

Из-за этого я сделал такую табличку, соответственно основная таблица без поля operatorId.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `chatOperator` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `chatId` BIGINT(6) NOT NULL,
  `userId` BIGINT(6) NOT NULL,
  `created` TIMESTAMP(6) NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`, `chatId`, `userId`),
  INDEX `fk_table1_chat1_idx` (`chatId` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_chatOperator_user1_idx` (`userId` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_table1_chat1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`chatId`)
    REFERENCES `chat` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_chatOperator_user1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`userId`)
    REFERENCES `user` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Но мне не очень нравится это т.к. в коде энтити есть поле operatorId, как в было в основной таблице.

Что можно еще сделать что бы избежать второй таблицы?

Comment: Возможно на уровне логики, в таблице операторов создать оператора "Выбираем" и с этим кодом запоминать  первую запись чата, потом уже можно произвести обновление на реальный код Оператора

Answer (score 1):

Если чат действительно, создается изначально без оператора (что странно), то тогда логично будет убрать ограничение `NOT NULL`.

Если убирать не хочется, то можно завести служебного оператора, скажем, с ID = 0 и прописывать ссылку на этого оператора

Answer (score 0):

`NOT NULL` надо убрать из поля `operatorId`. Тогда при вставке можно указывать значение `NULL`, после появления `operatorId` делать обновление.

Comment: легко не удастся:  
>> PRIMARY KEY (`id`, `siteId`, `clientId`, `operatorId`),

Comment: уберите его из ключа также